# iPhone showing checkboxes and radiobuttons

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I will have UInavigation controller and UITableView, it will be long scrolling list,for each cell I need to show some radiobuttons. checkboxes, date entries and textboxes. Since Iphone does not have these controls and considerding that I already Use UITableview and UINavigationContoller what is the best and easy practise here to show radiobuttons and checkboxes?

- pickerviews and putting them into a alertshield
- show them as tablelist items and multi/checkable
- using pickerview popping up from bottom as I have seen in some apps but dont know how to do that?

Comment: the iOS SDK doesn't include a radio button or checkbox UI element, so you will have to make one, unless you just want to use `UISwitch`.

**Checkboxes**  
http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/iphone-uibutton-tutorial-custom-checkboxes/  

**Radio buttons**  
http://www.developers-life.com/radio-buttons-in-iphone-application.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second choice is probably your best one. Look at how the Settings app lays things out: that should give you a good idea how to organize your options. Checkbox-able items are usually UISwitches; option-button-y ones are usually rows in a table view, with their corresponding UITableViewCell set to use `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark` as their `accessoryType` if they’re selected.

Comment: tnx If Im using a subclassed custom UITableViewCell, then can I use this approach? cause in custom cell there will be question label and unknown number of options that are multi selectable..?

Answer (score 3):

**Radio Buttons:** If the user has to select one among many items, you can use *UISegmentedControl*.

*Note: This method won't be a good solution if there are lot of items the user has to choose from.*

**Check Boxes:** You can implement this using *UIButtons* with some images like check boxes or something, and with some logic.

*Note: You can also implement radio buttons in this method.*

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes can be done by subclassing UIControl.  For future use I've already done this and all you have to do is download the link below from GitHub.  Also includes a sample project on how easy it is to use:

https://github.com/Brayden/UICheckbox